# Addsubview custom xib file error

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm using Swift 3, I have error adding xib file as subview

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomView", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    self.addSubview(view);
```

[image]

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Custom View Class i implemented as follow:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class TestView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        loadViewFromNib()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func loadViewFromNib(){
        let view =  Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("test", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! UIView
        print(view.backgroundColor ?? UIColor.blue)
    }
}
```

then In my ViewController where i want add this custom view i write as below:

```
let view = TestView()
```

and i dont find any crash.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is for swift 3.

```
let view =  Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! UIView
  self .addSubview(view)
```

Comment: Thanks, i still have error can you check this: https://i.gyazo.com/3be4695ec1fea3b97534f7fadbf60538.png